Dynamic Filtering of Non-Descriptive Adjectives and Nouns in Text Data?
How can I dynamically filter out non-descriptive adjectives and nouns from text data without relying on predefined lists?
I'm using spaCy for part-of-speech tagging and Named Entity Recognition, but I want a more dynamic approach. Any suggestions? Or should I try a whole different method?
import spacy
from collections import Counter

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = ""
doc = nlp(text)

def is_descriptive(adjective, noun):
    common_nouns = [list of common nouns that are not usefull]
    if noun.lower() in common_nouns:
        return False
    generic_adjectives = [list of generic adjectives that are not useful]
    if adjective.lower() in generic_adjectives:
        return False
    return True

phrases = []
for i in range(len(doc) - 1):
    if doc[i].pos_ == "ADJ" and doc[i + 1].pos_ == "NOUN" and is_descriptive(doc[i].text, doc[i + 1].text):
        phrases.append(f"{doc[i].text} {doc[i + 1].text}")

word_freq = Counter(phrases)

most_used_phrases = word_freq.most_common(10)
print("Adjective and Phrase Frequency")
for phrase, freq in most_used_phrases:
    print(f"{phrase} {freq}")


